# A simple but logical issue with file formatting using awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I am new to these awk and shell things and got stuck with a simple but logical issue ..

**Input File:**

```
6000 9876 5675 ....
8576 8765 9845 ...
....
```

**Output File: (required)**

```
60 00 98 76 56 75 ....
85 76 87 65 98 45 ...
....
```

Converting output to input is a rather easy task

```
awk '{printf("%s%s %s%s %s%s %s%s", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)}' output_file
                                                          > input_file
```

But converting input to output I am getting no guess

(also no. of fields are not known in advance although I think some logic with `NF` can solve this issue) but main problem is even if I know no. of fileds then how to proceed for that??

**The min. unit to be read wll be like `$1,$2` etc.. and I need to break them and need to insert a space between them.**

I don't know much about `regex` but trying my hand on it.May be some manipulation with `sed` and `regex` could help me out.

Please provide your valuable suggestons.`

Comment: Sorry for that wrong spelling of `formatting` in title .Thanx for the edit ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr -d ' ' < inputFile | sed 's/../& /g'
```

Alternatively to avoid the first tr:

```
sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/../& /g'
```

Comment: Can you explain what that `&` is doing exactly.As i have mentioned I am new to these things so asking just because of curiosity.

Comment: `&` means here the two characters to be substituted, i.e. the sed command tell to replace every sequence of two characters by themselves followed by a space character. The first tr command removes any space from the initial file to simplify the sed processing.

Comment: Would this leave a space before the newline?

Comment: As is, it will indeed but this issue would be easy to workaround: `... -e 's/ $//'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sed example:

```
$ echo "1234 5678 9012"|sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1 \2/g'
12 34 56 78 90 12
```

Comment: As you already know the input consists only of numbers and spaces perhaps `<<<"1234 5678 9012" sed -r 's/(..)(..)(\s)?/\1 \2\3/g'` might be suffice.

Answer (score 0):

since the question title mentioned "awk", I gave an awk solution though there is already accepted answer:

this needs gawk:

```
kent$  echo "6000 9876 5675
8576 8765 9845"|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=gensub(/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/,"\\1 \\2","g",$i);print }'                                    
60 00 98 76 56 75
85 76 87 65 98 45
```